# SoapUI 5.7.0 mockRequest.requestContent is empty for POST request

Tags: rest, post, mocking, soapui

I am using SOAP UI 5.7.0 to mock a REST service and it is working fine. Only, when I want to access the body of a **POST** request with `mockRequest.requestContent`, the correct content is returned only in the **first call**, but from then on, it always returns the **empty string**.

I tried the call in **OnRequestScript** and in the POST requests own **Dispatch script** but the behavior is the same in both cases. I have the suspicion, that the Stream of the request is already read somewhere else and so does not return any more content. But I don't know what to do about it.

I wonder what is the correct way to read the content of a POST request.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: This problem is driving me crazy.  Have you tried this with earlier version of SoapUI? Did it work?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a known issue, see posts in the community forum [here](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source-Questions/Getting-null-on-mockRequest-getRequestContent-in-one-of-REST/m-p/229102) and [here](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/ReadyAPI-Questions/Mock-Service-mockRequest-requestContent-is-NULL-HTTP-PUT/td-p/42138).

> this seems to be an old bug of PUT operation in REST mocks.

> Unfortunately, this is a bug. There is an internal defect of SOAP-2344 for this issue. This applies for the PUT and DELETE methods for a REST mock service.

I have the same issue with a PATCH request.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following trick to get the body of the `PUT` and `DELETE` requests:

```java
mockRequest.with {
    if (method.toString() == 'PUT' || method.toString() == 'DELETE') {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
        while ((s=br.readLine())!=null) { 
            sb.append(s)
        }

        def requestBody = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sb.toString())
        log.info "requestBody: " + requestBody
    }
}
```

I use it on the project but I don't really remember how where I got the snippet from. I had to change some parts to make it work as far as I remember. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I had 3 Soap mock services and 1 Rest mock service running.
If I started the Soap mocks first, the body from the rest service would be empty.
However, if the rest service started running before the Soap service, the body from the rest service would be OK.

Basically, start running the Rest service first